# Should we have a documentation tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Part of my job is to document risks, vulnerabilities, alerts, and security documentation for various aspects of InfoSec.

[Today I created the tag "documentation"](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/81947/396) to help collate this aspect of Infosec.

I find it funny that this tag doesn't exist in the 4 years of this site's existence, perhaps illustrating our communities' reluctance to do documentation, let alone ask questions about it.

I hope that by having this tag, we will make documentation easier for whomever is tasked with the arduous task of writing these reports, and similarly, for the person tasked with reading them.

Comment: How does this differ from our community wiki? What kind of questions do you forsee in this tag?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any reluctance to create documentation in the security community, nor to ask questions about it, however we have not had a need for one, and if I'm honest, I'm not sure that question you posted is even on topic - that sort of question is usually either opinion based, or has a specific regulation that requires certain documentation. Either way, not a lot of need for the tag.

That is however, just my own opinion.

Comment: I'm open to a close vote... / remove the tag.  I'll defer to you all.

Comment: As a mod vote trumps others, I'm going to defer to the community too.

Comment: On the on-topic subject, I think it might just be a bit too specific. The role of the PKI administrator is not clear, so I would change it to the point of view of the CISO (which has a full responsibility over the project)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is part of the job of a CISO for sure. The tag might be interesting to have because it would be easier to find question relating to this specific subject.

However we have to be careful not to accept (describe in the tag-wiki) a too broad scope here. We want to be able to have concrete answers to it, so questions like:

- What document do I need to comply to XXXX, is OK as it implies a straight forward (kindof) answer.

But :

- What document do I need to issue for customer of my XXX, would not be.

The current question might be a bit borderline as there is no clear qualification of the PKI administrator obligations.

Comment: Can you help me scope the question in a bit? I'm unsure of what PKI admins *do*, I'm mostly self taught here.  Some examples would be helpful

Comment: Well, that's the whole point of my remark. There is **no** description of the PKI admin job per se. It would depend your contract with your company, what you have access to.